# C# A Reverse Range ASCII Algorithm Method

Tags: c#

The code `if (opt == 1)` is the Forward counting of decimal `TotalValuePlus = NewcharDecimal + choice` and im looking for a way to reverse it for `else if (opt == 2)`. I cant seem to find a way of counting reverge method in the ASCII table. Like for example in my head when A (char) = 65 (dec) in ASCII table and the user inputs 3 (dec) and the choices Option 2 (which is subtraction) then the answer should be X (char) = 88 (dec).

The question is *how to do this in Math Algorithm Method?* or am I approaching it the wrong way? If I'm approaching the wrong way. What should I do?
thanks in advance who would reply and to read this.

So here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.Write("Geben Sie bitte eine zu verschlüsselnde Nummer ein: ");
            string newWords = Console.ReadLine();
            string newWords2 = newWords.ToUpper();
            Console.Write("Welchen Abstand möchten Sie? ");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            decimal choice = Convert.ToDecimal(num1);
            Console.Write("Wählen Sie Zählen vorwärts (1) oder rückwärts zählen (2) ");
            string opt = Console.ReadLine();

            newWords2 = newWords2.Replace("Ö", "OE");
            newWords2 = newWords2.Replace("Ä", "AE");
            newWords2 = newWords2.Replace("Ü", "UE");
            newWords2 = newWords2.Replace("ß", "SS");
            newWords2 = newWords2.Replace(" ", " ");



            Char[] arrayNewWords = newWords2.ToCharArray();



            foreach (char Newchar in arrayNewWords)
            {

                decimal a = Convertion(Newchar, choice, opt);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                char c = Convert.ToChar(b);
                string result = c.ToString();

                // Console.Write(value);
                Console.Write(result);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        public static decimal Convertion(char Newchar, decimal choice, string opt)
        {

            decimal NewcharDecimal = Convert.ToInt32(Newchar);


            decimal TotalTotal = 0;




                if (opt == "1")
                {
                    decimal TotalValuePlus = NewcharDecimal + choice;

                    while ((TotalValuePlus > 90) || (TotalValuePlus < 64))
                    {

                        if (TotalValuePlus >= 90)
                        {
                            TotalValuePlus -= 90;


                        }
                        else if (TotalValuePlus <= 64)
                        {
                            TotalValuePlus += 64;

                        }

                    }

                    if ((TotalValuePlus <= 90) && (TotalValuePlus >= 65))
                    {
                        TotalTotal = TotalValuePlus;
                       // return TotalTotal;

                    }


                 } 


                else if (opt == "2")
                {
                    decimal TotalValueMinus = NewcharDecimal - choice;

                    while ((TotalValueMinus > 90) || (TotalValueMinus < 64))
                    {

                        if (TotalValueMinus >= 90)
                        {
                            TotalValueMinus += 90;


                        }
                        else if (TotalValueMinus <= 64)
                        {
                            TotalValueMinus -= 64;

                        }

                    }

                    if ((TotalValueMinus <= 90) && (TotalValueMinus >= 65))
                    {
                        TotalTotal = TotalValueMinus;

                       // return TotalTotal;
                    }

                }
                return TotalTotal;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got a new Problem when i now make a range big range and in it is with a range. i cant seem to figure out how to skip the Counts for the mid range when the end number does not land at the mid range.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is unecessarily complicated. Study and understand the following:

```
public static char Offset(char c, int offset, char lowerBound, char upperBound)
{
    var mod = (c + offset - lowerBound) % (upperBound - lowerBound + 1);
    var newChar = (char)(mod >= 0 ? lowerBound + mod: upperBound + mod + 1);
    Debug.Assert(lowerBound <= newChar && newChar <= upperBound);
    return newChar;
}
```

Things to consider:

1. `ASCII` encoding is based on [natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), why are you converting to `decimal`? Also, `char` is implicitly convertible to `int`, you don't need to explicitly convert anything.
2. Learn about the `%` operator, and how [modulus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.100).aspx) is useful in this kind of scenarios. Hint: remove the ugly while loops in your code.
3. Why are you using an unweildly argument to decide if the offset is positive or negative? Simply use the sign of the offset itself.
4. Whenever possible implement cheap generalization (if its not cheap then don't do it unless strictly necessary); why hard code the lower and upper bounds of the interval? It's easy to generalize this method for any valid interval.
5. Implement argument validation. If the method is public, throw a meaningful exception if the supplied arguments are not valid. If the method is internal or private consider using [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert(v=vs.110).aspx).
6. [Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert(v=vs.110).aspx) method post conditions. Make sure your invariants are held and the method is working as expected.

*UPDATE*: A more general solution to the problem is given by the following extension method:

```
public static T Offset<T>(this IList<T> source, int start, int offset)
{
    var mod = (start + offset) % source.Count;
    return source[mod >= 0 ? mod : source.Count + mod + 1];
}
```

Reading your comments, this version might be more useful:

```
var str = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var thirteenth = str.ToCharArray().Offset(0, 13);
```

Comment: thanks InBetween for your answer. It's a bit clear for me now.

Comment: And what if i would like to control what would be used. Assume that digits and uppercase letters form a unit: 0123456789ABCDEFGH ... XYZ.

From "0", the offset "13" becomes "D", and "Z" becomes "M" instead of "C".

Comment: is there a way to skip a column/row in the ASCII table? cause sadly i Need to stick with the first program. Because the input Offset should be adjustable..